# Can someone help me to find the mean of the column x for every minute in R language

Tags: r

The data looks like this.

[image]

The output i am expecting is as below. x should be the mean/average of every minute.

[image: Expected output]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you try it first by yourself and show us, what you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a crude solution, but here you go:

```
# Packages needed for solution
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

# A minimal example of your data
data <- data.frame(time = c("November 3rd 2016, 14:22:37.304", "November 3rd 2016, 14:22:37.352",
                        "November 3rd 2016, 14:32:47.816", "November 3rd 2016, 14:32:50.816",
                        "November 3rd 2016, 15:32:47.816", "November 3rd 2016, 15:32:50.816"),
                    x = c(1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5))

# Solution
data %>%
  separate(time, c("month", "day", "year", "hour", 
           "minute", "second", "millisecond")) %>%
  group_by(hour, minute) %>%
  summarise(mean(x))

# Result
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   hour [?]
  hour  minute `mean(x)`
  <chr> <chr>      <dbl>
1 14    22          1.25
2 14    32          2.25
3 15    32          3.25
```

First, `separate` makes your messy date variable easier to handle by splitting it up into its components (there is most definitely a better way to do this). The column `minutes` contains the information you need to calculate your grouped means. By using `group_by()` in conjunction with `summarise()`, the mean value for each minute is calculated.

This being said, it would be great if you made your question reproducible by providing your actual data rather than a screenshot and also show us what you have tried so far in dealing with your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can I know how to display the complete datetime instead of only minute in the output. Also I was trying the method shown in the link https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7268/how-to-aggregate-by-minute-data-for-a-week-into-hourly-means.. but I couldnt succeed.

Comment: The above method doesn't work when the hour change, is there any other way for achieving this?

Comment: Yeah, you can use `group_by()` on both `hour` and `minute`. If recurring days and months are also a problem, just add those columns to the call to `group_by()`. I have edited my answer to reflect that